# Access Foreign Key's Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-annotate

I have these models:

```
class Source(models.Model):
    name          = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    feed_url      = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    ....

class Post(models.Model):
    source        = models.ForeignKey(Source, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    title         = models.TextField(blank=True)
    body          = models.TextField()
    ....

class FeedCategory(models.Model):
    feed_category = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=FEED_CATEGORIES, blank=True)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And I want to make a Queryset where I get all `FeedCategories` but I'd like to also include in there their related posts. So If I use:

```
    feeds = FeedCategory.objects.select_related('source').all()
```

my queryset does not return the posts. I tried using:

```
    feeds = FeedCategory.objects.select_related('source').all()
    posts = Post.objects.filter(source_id__in=feeds.values_list('source_id', flat=True))
```

which works but its on two different queries.
What I basically want to do is have a single query which shows the category and the related source's posts in order to bring them up on frontend so I could use something like:

```
{% for feed in feeds %} 
   {{feed.category}}
   {% for post in feed.source_set %}
       {{post.body}}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

My thinking was something with annotate but how exactly do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
In `for post in feed.source_set` source_set contains `Source` objects. Not Posts. You need to go deeper since there could be many `Posts` in one `Source` and there can be manu `Sources` in one `FeedCategory`

```
{% for feed in feeds %} 
   {{feed.category}}
   {% for source in feed.source_set.all %}
       {% for post in source.posts.all %}
           {{post.body}}
       {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

About the query. I'm almost sure you can't do that insingle query. This is possible only if there is single foreign key. Since you can have many connection then you should use `prefetch_related`

Try:

```
feeds = FeedCategory.objects.prefetch_related('source', "source__posts").all()
```

This should do at most 3 queries if I'm not missing something

Comment: `source` does not have a `posts` field though so `source__posts` is wrong isnt it?

Comment: It kinda does. In the Post class you have FK to source with related name specified `related_name='posts'`